# Javascript - Unable to call function inside a foreach loop

Tags: javascript

I think I'm fundamentally misunderstanding something here in Javascript.

Could someone please explain why I get `SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` when trying to call `getUrlContent` from inside the forEach:

```
(async () => {

    let sitesState = []
    urlsToCheck.forEach(url => {
        sitesState.push({
            "url": url,
            "data": await getUrlContent(url)
        })
    })

})();

async function getUrlContent(url) { ... }
```

Why does this happen (and of course, how do I write this correctly?).

Any help appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Does this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop

Comment: Yes, That helps very much :)

Answer (score 1):

You've used `async` in the wrong function. Check this.

```
    ( () => {

    let sitesState = []
    urlsToCheck.forEach(async(url) => {
        sitesState.push({
            "url": url,
            "data": await getUrlContent(url)
        })
    })

})();

async function getUrlContent(url) { ... }
```